# Are UI.Diagrams supported in in KendoUI for Angular 2

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I'm looking into develope a single page app with AngularJS 2 and need advanced diagram UI.

I can see that KendoUI has good Diagram components. However I just find out about KendoUI for Angular 2 but not sure diagrams are supported.

Is it supported or is going to be supported any time soon?
Is there any other UI framework options for AngularJS 2 app with advanced diagram components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the current beta version of Kendo UI for Angular 2 doesn't offer a Diagram. The addition of this component is slated for the second half of next year. Here is the current [Kendo UI for Angular 2 Roadmap](http://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/roadmap/).

Comment: I don't see it in the roadmap yet. When do we expect to see it?